# Zip a byte array in Go

Tags: zip, go

I am trying to take a chunk of bytes and compress them using the `archive/zip` package in Go. However, I can't understand it at all. Are there any examples of how it could be done and is there any explanation of that cryptic package?

Comment: There's an example in the documentation for the package -- http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Writer

Comment: Downvoted for “This question does not show any research effort”. Please tell us what you tried, and/or which references you used (e.g. official zip package, the functions you tried and seemed to match, but did not work).

Comment: @Kissaki One of the first barriers one has to overcome when learning a new computer language is making sense of the documentation. I put quite a lot of effort into trying to understand it, and writing bits of code that didn't make any sense at all. The last straw was that I found an article about the zip package that stated that "write() method was removed from Writer, because putting it there had been a mistake". That blew my mind completely and I turned to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks to jamessan I did find the example (which doesn't exactly catch your eye).

Here is what I come up with as the result:

```
func (this *Zipnik) zipData() {

    // Create a buffer to write our archive to.
    fmt.Println("we are in the zipData function")
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Create a new zip archive.
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)

    // Add some files to the archive.
    var files = []struct {
        Name, Body string
    }{
        {"readme.txt", "This archive contains some text files."},
        {"gopher.txt", "Gopher names:\nGeorge\nGeoffrey\nGonzo"},
        {"todo.txt", "Get animal handling licence.\nWrite more examples."},
    }
    for _, file := range files {
    zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(file.Name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        _, err = zipFile.Write([]byte(file.Body))  
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    // Make sure to check the error on Close.
    err := zipWriter.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //write the zipped file to the disk
    ioutil.WriteFile("Hello.zip", buf.Bytes(), 0777)    

}
```

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer.  It helps others see that the question is resolved to your satisfaction.

Comment: How to write a test around this? how do you read from a buffer created for a zip?

Comment: Hi if you are meaning convert from a byte array to string before calling the zip this tells you how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230145/how-can-i-convert-a-zero-terminated-byte-array-to-string. The above look like it only puts string content to ZIP.

Comment: you need to import `archive/zip` for this