# How to convert byte array to string in Go

Tags: go, types, sha1

`[]byte` to string raises an error.
`string([]byte[:n])` raises an error too.
By the way, for example, sha1 value to string for filename.
Does it need utf-8 or any other encoding set explicitly? 
Thanks!

Comment: `[]byte` can be converted directly to `string`. Please show an example of what problem you're having.

Comment: eg. file hash value  to string for filename

Comment: If you just show us an example of what you tried, it would be a very easy question to answer, rather than waiting for us to guess the correct answer.

Comment: In most modern languages it would be perfectly clear what he was trying to do, sadly, and without any additional context needed. I also stumbled upon this question looking for the same answer (as answered below).

Comment: @JimB Byte arrays cannot be directly converted to a string. Only byte slices.

Comment: you can use base64: import ("encoding/base64") which could be shorter than hex.

Answer (score 208):

The easiest method I use to convert `byte` to `string` is:

```
myString := string(myBytes[:])
```

Comment: Why the `:`? What's the difference between this answer and `myString := string(myBytes)`?

Comment: The `:` is needed because byte *arrays* cannot be directly turned to a string while slices can. Let's say we have `var b [64]byte` . `string(b)` will fail while `string(b[:])` will work.

Answer (score 113):

The easiest way to convert `[]byte` to `string` in Go:

```
myString := string(myBytes)
```

---

Note: to convert a "*sha1 value to string*" like you're asking, it needs to be *encoded* first, since a hash is binary. The traditional encoding for SHA hashes is hex (`import "encoding/hex"`):

```
myString := hex.EncodeToString(sha1bytes)
```

Comment: Does the string contain a copy of the bytes?

Comment: Yes, it contains an immutable copy of the bytes.

Answer (score 16):

In Go you convert a byte array (utf-8) to a string by doing `string(bytes)` so in your example, it should be `string(byte[:n])` assuming `byte` is a slice of bytes.

Comment: I have just try like this.but failed. In fact ,I need to convert a file sha1 value to string ,named for the filename

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure that i understand question correctly, but may be:

```
var ab20 [20]byte = sha1.Sum([]byte("filename.txt"))
var sx16 string = fmt.Sprintf("%x", ab20)
fmt.Print(sx16)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/haChjjsH0-

Comment: While technically correct, it's rather unusual in Go to use `var` and declare every type without just inferring them. https://play.golang.org/p/JUl57LKfzk

Comment: Ah! "%x"! That's what I was doing wrong! :) I was using the wrong Sprintf placeholder, duh...

Comment: You could also use `hex.EncodeToString` instead of `fmt.Sprintf("%x", ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ToBe := [6]byte{65, 66, 67, 226, 130, 172}
s:=ToBe[:3]
// this will work
fmt.Printf("%s",string(s))
// this will not
fmt.Printf("%s",string(ToBe))
```

Difference : ToBe is an array whereas s is a slice.

Answer (score 1):

First you're getting all these negatives reviews because you didn't provided any code.
Second, without a good example. This is what i'd do

```
var Buf bytes.Buffer
Buf.Write([]byte)
myString := Buf.String()
Buf.Reset() // Reset the buffer to reuse later
```

or better yet

```
myString := string(someByteArray[:n])
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230145/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-byte-array-to-string) also see @JimB's comment

That being said if you help that targets your program, please provide and example of what you've tried, the expect results, and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. EncodeToString returns the hexadecimal encoding of src.it works well.

Answer (score 0):

We can just guess what is wrong with your code because no meaningful example is provided. But first what I see that `string([]byte[:n])` is not valid at all. `[]byte[:n]` is not a valid expression because no memory allocated for the array. Since byte array could be converted to string directly I assume that you have just a syntax error.

Shortest valid is `fmt.Println(string([]byte{'g', 'o'}))`