# Python bytes() or bytesarray() counterpart in golang

Tags: python, go

I am looking to port some code from python into golang.
The code in python goes like this

```
to_be_converted = [3, 40, 234, 1, 23, 65, 43, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
converted = bytes(to_be_converted)
print(converted)
```

this results to

```
b'\x03(\xea\x01\x17A+Hello world'
```

I am looking for a way to get this bytes object in golang.
I dont mind if the input data is different, I am only looking for a way to obtain the output.
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261008/5927361

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632802/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-go

Comment: Do you specifically want the exact string `b'\x03(\xea\x01\x17A+Hello world'`? If so, you should clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go has a builtin byte type and you can create byte arrays like this:

```
myBytes := []byte{3, 40, 234, 1, 23, 65, 43, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100}
```

To get the string output, you can just convert the byte array to a string like this:

```
myString := string(myBytes)
fmt.Println(myString)// prints (�A+Hello world
```

Comment: To get output closer to what the OP wanted, one would use the `%q` verb with `fmt.Printf`, which also accepts `[]byte` and does not require type-conversion to `string`.