# Null-terminated []byte to string doesn't work

Tags: go

I have a slice of bytes to represent a null-terminated string with trailing garbage bytes.

I followed [How can I convert a zero-terminated byte array to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230145/how-can-i-convert-a-zero-terminated-byte-array-to-string)

```
s := string(byteArray[:n])
```

but it doesn't work

```
[54 49 0 101 0 0 0 0 64 31 1 0 0]
61e@
```

instead of just `61`

I've also tried to trim the slice: `bytes.Trim(buf[:], "\x00")` same result.

https://go.dev/play/p/FDPPLgGjHOY

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first find where the 0 is:

```
ix:=bytes.IndexByte(byteArray,0)
if ix==-1 {
  ix=len(byteArray)
}
s:=string(byteArray[:ix])
```

Comment: I tried to use a method that should do exactly that `bytes.Trim(buf[:], "\x00")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Trim only removes leading/trailing zeros, in this case, the last two

Comment: Too bad there isn't a similar method to trim a slice once a value is found. And what a confusing name `bytes.Trim` that actually doesn't trim...
Thanks! I used your code and it worked.